# python tox: how to use a different python envlist in environment

Tags: python, tox

Here is my tox.ini:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27,py35

[testenv]
deps =
    Flask
    connexion
    pytest
    coverage
    pytest-cov
    requests
    six
commands=pytest --junitxml xunit-reports/xunit-result-XXX.xml --cov {envsitepackagesdir} --cov-report=xml

[testenv:local]
#HOW DO I SPECIFY A NEW LIST OF PYENV LIKE 31,36 IN HERE????
commands=
    pytest --cov {envsitepackagesdir}/XXX  --cov-report html
```

When I run `tox` it runs in `py27` and `py35`. I want `tox -e local` to run in a different set of multiple python environments. I can't figure out how to do this. How do I do this? Right now it does not even respect the intial envlist and only runs on Python 2.7.

Answer (score 17):

So what you want is to have two different sets of environments and run them independently.

What you have to understand first is that `envlist` is a list of all environments that would be run if you invoke tox without the `-e` option.

The next thing you have to understand is that there is only one of these lists per `tox.ini` and that one is in the global `[tox]` section.

The other thing you have to understand is that the pyXX factors (factors are the parts of environment names that are separated by the `-` sign) have a special meaning for tox, because they instruct it to build an environment with a specific interpreter. They are also called "default environments" (see [basic usage](http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html#a-simple-tox-ini-default-environments)). If you don't ask for that factor when calling tox, then the `basepython` interpreter will be used to build the virtualenv (the interpreter you are invoking tox from).

so if you invoke `tox -e local` with a tox.ini like yours, it will execute what is defined in `[tox:local]` with the basepython, because you are not defining which python should be used to create the virtualenv, so it uses the same interpreter that you invoked tox with.

If you want to be able to invoke your local factor with other interpreters, independent from those other environments, the following could get you started (described in the [v2 config docs](http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-v2.html)):

```
[tox]
envlist = {py27,py35}-remote,{py31,py36}-local

[testenv]
deps =
    Flask
    connexion
    pytest
    coverage
    pytest-cov
    requests
    six

[testenv:remote]
commands=pytest --junitxml xunit-reports/xunit-result-XXX.xml --cov {envsitepackagesdir} --cov-report=xml

[testenv:local]
commands= pytest --cov {envsitepackagesdir}/XXX --cov-report html
```

Check which envs this creates with:

```
$ tox -a

py27-remote
py35-remote
py31-local
py36-local
```

What envlist with the curly braces notation does, is create environment names by combining all factors with their permutations (this can have more dimensions also).

if you say tox without `-e` they will all run and all use the correct interpreter.

If you want to run the local envs only you will have to call it with:

```
$ tox -e py31-local,py36-local
```

or say the same thing smarter, if you like (thanks [@phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) for the hint):

```
$ tox -e 'py{31,36}'-local
```

Then only those two will run. The thing to take away here is that if you want to run a subset of all environments you have to ask for them with their full names. There is no "sub generation" or extra envlist magic. Just list the full names of the envirenments in a comma separated list and you are golden.

Comment: TIL learned about the [RAS syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome) :)

Answer (score 9):

A possible solution to what you are attempting to do is to use `tox -l` to list all the environments, filter the ones you want, and then feed them back into `tox -e`.

For example, to run all environments that have "local" in the name (using bash):

`tox -e $(tox -l | grep local | paste -sd "," -)`

Step-by-step explanation:

- `tox -l` lists all the environments, one on each line
- `grep local` filters only the lines of the input which contain the word "local"
- `paste -sd "," -` joins the lines of the input with commas

Comment: **Least insane answer.** Everything else requires manual intervention and thus violates DRY (e.g., by either [explicitly listing `tox` environments at the CLI with `-e`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46208073/2809027) *or* [defining a separate CLI-specific `tox-local.ini` entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46209122/2809027)), which is insane. Instead, just stuff the above one-liner into a shell script or shell alias in `~/.zshrc` (e.g., `alias toxit='tox -e $(tox -l | grep local | paste -sd "," -)'`). Feel the exhilarating freedom of automation that does all the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 4):

`[tox]envlist` is only a default — a list of environments to run when `tox` is invoked without option `-e` and without `TOXENV` environment variable. Once you use `tox -e` `[tox]envlist` is ignored.

You can run `local` environment with different python versions, but I don't know any way to run it multiple times. You have to list all environments explicitly:

```
tox -e py33-local,py34-local
```

You can shorten the command line using tox' conventions:

```
tox -e 'py3{3,4}'-local
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [generative envlist and factor-conditional settings](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#generating-environments-conditional-settings).

```
[tox]
envlist = {py27,py31,py35,py36}-{default,local}

[testenv]
deps =
    Flask
    connexion
    pytest
    coverage
    pytest-cov
    requests
    six

commands =
    {default,local}: python --version
    default: pytest --junitxml xunit-reports/xunit-result-XXX.xml --cov {envsitepackagesdir} --cov-report=xml
    local: pytest --cov {envsitepackagesdir}/XXX  --cov-report html
```

List all possible combinations of python version and factors using: `tox -l`

For your "local" case you'd invoke tox in the one of the following ways:

- `tox -e py31-local`
- `tox -e py36-local`
- `tox -e 'py3{1,6}'-local`

---

Answer heavily influenced by [@oliver-bestwalter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2626627/oliver-bestwalter)'s answer, but I couldn't get that to work properly for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

OK I greatly appreciate and upvoted the other two answers here but what I ended up doing was different. It seemed onerous just to achieve a separate 
 python version and command.
What I ended up doing was just making a seperate tox.ini and calling it like `tox -c tox-local.ini`